# OneSignal Notification not working on iOS 10

Tags: xcode, push-notification, swift3, apple-push-notifications, onesignal

Notifications from OneSiganl for iOS 10 is not working. things i have rechecked again that i am using..

Xcode 8.1,
Swift 3,
Added latest provisioning cert,
Under capabilities push notifications are on with entitlement,

My app delegate methods are

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

  OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: ONE_SIGNAL_APPID)
    OneSignal.setLogLevel(.LL_VERBOSE, visualLevel: .LL_NONE)
    OneSignal.promptLocation();
   OneSignal.initWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions, appId: ONE_SIGNAL_APPID, handleNotificationReceived: {

        (Notification) in            

    }, handleNotificationAction: { (action) in

    }, settings:[kOSSettingsKeyAutoPrompt: true ,
                  kOSSettingsKeyInFocusDisplayOption:OSNotificationDisplayType.notification.rawValue]) }
```

And for registering the device with id.

```
     func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {


     OneSignal.sendTag("myType", value: "myBroadCast")

    OneSignal.idsAvailable { (userId, deviceToken) in

        let userId = String(format: "%@", userId!)
        DataManager.sharedInstance.deviceToken = userId;

        print("player id",userId)
    }
```

I have got the playerid i.e userId apparently. So my device is registered successfully.

The thing is that the api notifications are not receiving on my device. Other than OneSignal sample push messages (which are working fine),

My API payload for notification is

```
    {"alert":{"notification":{"notification_type":1,"v_n":"Custom Place","u_n":"customer","c_id":907,"m_id":1207,"m_t":"1","f_a":0,"d_d":"07 Dec, 2016","t_t":"07:40 AM","is_group_chat":true},"body":"hxuf"},"badge":1,"sound":"NewMessage.mp3"}
```

Please help me in this regard. As this problem is only with iOS 10 devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your making a POST REST API call to https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications your JSON format isn't correct. The JSON payload should be as follows for the OneSignal notification based on your contents from your JSON example in your question.

```
{
   "app_id": "YOUR_ONESIGNAL_APP_ID",
   "contents": {"en": "hxuf"},
   "ios_badgeType": "SetTo",
   "ios_badgeCount": 1,
   "ios_sound":"NewMessage.mp3",
   "data": {"notification_type":1,"v_n":"Custom Place","u_n":"customer","c_id":907,"m_id":1207,"m_t":"1","f_a":0,"d_d":"07 Dec, 2016","t_t":"07:40 AM","is_gr`oup_chat":true}
}
```

**Note1:** You must set a targeting parameter such as `include_player_ids` as a JOSN array to a list of OneSignal player / user ids. Or use another targeting parameter such as `included_segments`. See the full tarting options in the OneSignal documentation page at the bottom of this answer.

**Note2:** .mp3 files can't be used for notification sounds for iOS. You must convert it to a .wav or .caf format.

See OneSignal's full documentation on the create REST API call endpoint below.
https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference#create-notification

Comment: Thank you very much. The payload was in wrong format.